# How can I disable the Auto Save feature for ALL Excel Spread Sheets and not just individually?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How can I disable the Auto Save feature for ALL Excel Spread Sheets and not just individually, for Excell 2007?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Options (under main menu) --> Save --> uncheck "Save AutoRecover information every ___ minutes"